# PHP Sendmail fails if there is a period on the message text

Tags: php, sendmail

This seems kind of weird, and there is nothing I could find about.

Sending this via php -a

```
 echo mail("xxx@xyz.com", "message from xyz.com", "this is a message from xyz.com");
```

Results in no message received at the other end, but if I remove all the periods from the subject AND message as in:

```
 echo mail("me@me.com", "message from xyzcom", "this is a message from xyzcom");
```

Then the message is successfully received successfully.

I understand that a terminating period is allowed, so how are other periods accomplished?
Note that BOTH of the above return TRUE from PHP mail();

Comment: am certain this is not your code, so before the message is sent, validation checks for any URL  or domain. if available {dont send message}. this is done for security

Comment: Do you want to know how it's done? how to bypass that validation

Comment: Dean, Yes!  Can't find the answer, and I'm sure it is a simple one!  Decades of programming and never used sendmail!

Comment: mail(); function is disabled on most of servers due to security reason.

Comment: Not receiving an email does not mean that it was not _sent_ successfully. See [this old chestnut](https://superuser.com/a/748231/149953). If those "illegal periods" are your domain name it is entirely possible that your domain is blacklisted in a _content_ filter, and I have had that happen at a company when the CEO sent some "marketing" emails. Long story short, there's a lot more in the delivery chain for you to look at.

Answer (score 0):

The comments provided me some hints to what was happening and my immediate problem was solved by simply whitelisting the source mail IP address.
And, that only works because the PHP mail destination is always the same address (it is contact page data).

I also realize that I need a more sophisticated email arrangement than basic PHP mail, so I will install a good smtp server which will alleviate problems like this.